# Activate CSS Animation When User Scrolls to that Part of Page

Tags: html, css, animation

I am just trying to make the following code's animation to nly become active when the user scrolls to that part of the page. This only needs to happen once, until the page is refreshed the animation can happen again.

```
    <ul class="skill-list">
      <li class="skill">
        <h3>Nunchucks</h3>
        <progress class="skill-1" max="100" value="50">
          <strong>Skill Level: 50%</strong>
        </progress>
      </li>
      <li class="skill">
        <h3>Bow Staff</h3>
        <progress class="skill-2" max="100" value="75">
          <strong>Skill Level: 75%</strong>
        </progress>
      </li>
      <li class="skill">
        <h3>Roundhouse Kick</h3>
        <progress class="skill-3" max="100" value="25">
          <strong>Skill Level: 25%</strong>
        </progress>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

here is the CSS:

```
<!-- skill chart -->
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

progress, progress[role] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.skill-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.skill {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.skill h3 {
  color: #fff;
  left: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}
.skill ::-webkit-progress-value {
  -webkit-animation: bar-fill 2s;
  width: 0px;
}

.skill-1::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #ff9e2c;
}

.skill-1::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #ff9e2c;
}

.skill-2::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #4ecdc4;
}

.skill-2::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #4ecdc4;
}

.skill-3::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #ff6b6b;
}

.skill-3::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #ff6b6b;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bar-fill {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bar-fill {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I really want to do this with out having to add a bunch of code. Can anyone tell me how to do this in a simple way, and please explain the process. cause the answer below is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a script that can track the scroll position, here is wow.js

https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

Comment: okay thanks, so one I get this script. how can I implement it

Comment: also is this the only way to do it? It seems over complicated, so many files to download for one simple thing